# Canvas object: semi circle leaking colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I want to understand the essentials of opening and closing function of canvas .
What I noticed was when I used only one opening and closing of function of canvas for 2 separate object a rectangle and a semi circle. The colour started leaking as shown:

[image: figure 1:result noticed]

What I expect is as below figure 2. With one opening and closing canvas function:

[image: figure 2 result expected]

The code is mentioned below

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(30, 30, 50, 60);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(350,200,20,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();



ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! IT ONLY MAKES PEOPLE ANGRY AND NOT WANT TO HELP YOU!

Comment: If you port your code to FORTRAN then you can use upper case there too.

Comment: The code you mentioned doesn't produce the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `ctx.beginPath` create a new path object by deleting all existing paths points and strokes

The function `ctx.closePath` creates a line from the last point added to the current path to the previous `ctx.moveTo` or `ctx.beginPath` it is unrelated to the `ctx.beginPath` function and does nothing if followed by `ctx.beginPath`

The function `ctx.closePath` is the same as `ctx.lineTo` in the following

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);  // back to start
```

Same as

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,200);
ctx.closePath(); // does the same as ctx.lineTo(100,100);  // back to start
```

Some comments in your code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(30, 30, 50, 60);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();   // <<< Not needed as you have already called fill

ctx.beginPath();   // <<< this deletes the previous path
ctx.arc(350,200,20,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();

ctx.closePath(); // <<< not needed
```